# react-native-image-crop-picker compile debug java with javac failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, npm, react-native-image-crop-picker

`# Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED**`

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```

`

How to solve this error, please give me solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be issue with the current version, so downgrade react-native-image-picker to 0.38.1

Note: usually downgrading is not a good idea, since it might be outdated or buggy. However, some new-released versions might not support or buggy that previous versions have been working well.

clean the rebuild the gradle again

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```